Callout exception - OAuth token error
I am trying to call an API that requires Client credentials flow for token generation. I have configured external credentials and also configured named credentials using the external credentials created earlier.
EC Configuration

NC Configuration

Apex test
Testing the above configuration in apex first before taking it to development.
// httprequest object
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:MyNamedCred' + '/somevalidationURL' );
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
// make the callout
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

When I ran the above code in the Anonymous window in developer console, I get the following error

System.CalloutException: Unable to fetch the OAuth token. Error:
access_denied. Error description: No audience parameter was provided,
and no default audience has been configured.

What have I tried

Calling the APIs successfully from Postman. Please check the curl request below (from Postman)
curl --location 'someURL/oauth/token' 
--header 'content-type: application/json' 
--data '{
"client_id": "[CLIEND_ID]",
"client_secret": "[CLIENT_SECRET]",
"audience": "https://API.SOMEURL.COM/",
"grant_type": "client_credentials"
}'


I get the token and feed it in my next API call
curl --location 'https://api.SOMEURL.com/APIvalidation' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN_GENERATED_ABOVE' 
--header 'Cookie: [SOME_VALUE]' 
--data '{
"person": {
"personName": {
"familyName": "Howe",
"firstName": "Casey"
}
}
}'

Edit
I have put "audience" in the header of EC but still same error.


Postman snapshot for reference


This is pretty far from oAuth-standard client_credentials grant type. You can still implement this via Named/External Credentials - use Custom scheme in Ext Cred and merge params in the request body.

Is there an example to use custom schemes

See Q&A above for merge syntax, the rest is the same as if you were using a legacy Named Cred + Apex

@identigral - I have put the "audience" parameter in the header (plz see edit) still getting the same error.

Won't help, you're still very far off from oAuth standard grant (read the spec)
